# normalizing dialogue, what approach

Tags: dialogue

what is the right level to normalize dialogue, it is a short movie very low budget, the target is some indy film festival, somebdoy just told me to stay  with dynamic range between -18 and -6db, but what about the -27 i read often here about dialogue? seems really to be so low.

Answer (score 1):

"with dynamic between -18 and -6" doesn't mean anything. Dynamic what? Dynamic range?

Maybe your peaks would hit between -18 and -6, but an RMS or LeqA (which is what -27 is referring to) should not be getting anywhere near that. If you think that sounds too quiet, then it's likely you need to properly calibrate your system: http://www.dynamicinterference.com/blog/2010/09/quick-and-dirty-monitor-calibration/

Comment: I'm guessing what may have been the confusion is that they read that dialnorm is supposed to peg the meters at -27, and 'dialnorm' was misunderstood to mean 'dialogue (peak) normalization', when of course that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

right after the video editing, when i import audio project in daw and start to work on dialogue, what the dynamic range to care about dialogue? I am not relating mixing but dialogue editing.

Comment: Shaun's answer is correct for both editorial and mix.  It should be a 'relatively' 1:1 process through editorial and mix (in that the levels are appropriately chosen).  Almost always as an OMF or AAF required a global re-balance to the general level Shaun stated before I even dig in and edit.  it's all about proper evaluation of the dialogue - without properly calibrating it, one can't properly evaluate it. 